# Conditional Image Src Binding in angular 2

Tags: angular

How to write the ternany condition for `<img>` `src` in Angular 2.

Below is the code I tried but this is not working

```
<img class="lib-img" [src]="item.pictureUrl!= null ? item.pictureUrl : ~/images/logo.png" height="500" width="500" alt="default image">
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
[src]="item.pictureUrl!= null ? item.pictureUrl : myImgUrl"
```

then in your 
**.ts**

```
export class App{
   myImgUrl:string='~/images/logo.png';
}
```

Comment: I, can see the image location but the image is not been loaded.In src there is a image location.

Comment: In html the src= '~/images/logo.png'. But the image is not load

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Dnj8eKDRwShmIb4HQUT4?p=preview this is working fine according to your requirement. just comment first one and uncomment second line, you'll get the result.

Answer (score 17):

```
[src]="item.pictureUrl ? item.pictureUrl : 'assets/img/logo.png'"
```

Maybe better way is to keep your images in assets folder: **assets/img/logo.png**

Answer (score 3):

```
<img [src]="item.pictureUrl!= null ? 'link/to/image1.png' : 
'link/to/image2.png'">
```

This will do the trick

For more binding information follow this link

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**For those looking to conditionally provide the `src` attribute to the `<img>` element:**

Use [Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<img [attr.src]="item.pictureUrl" />
```

If the expression `item.pictureUrl` evaluates to null, the `src` attribute will be removed from the `<img>` element

Comment: I was looking to do the conditional thing for `width` and `height`, and this worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use variable in image `#svg` to get source `svg.getAttribute('src')`, you need implement method to get image in ts file instead of if else in html file.

I shared for whom concerned.

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of svgFiles" class="listItem">
    <a draggable="true" class="nav-link" (dragstart)="onDrag($event, 14, svg.getAttribute('src'))">
        <img [src]="getImage(widget)" #svg />                           
    </a>
    <p>{{widget.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

TS file

```
getImage(widget) {
        if (this.isRootSearch) {
            return `./assets/svg${widget}`;
        } else {
            return `./assets/svg/${this.selectedSVGFolder}/${widget}`;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working.

Answer (score 2):

.html

```
[src]="validateURL(item.pictureUrl)"
```

.ts

```
validateURL(url) {
    let valid = /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(url);
    if (valid)
      return url;
    else
      return '';// or "link/to/image1.png"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<img [src]="imageSrc || 'images/default.png'" />
```

imageSrc is a variable in my JS class. If imageSrc is null or undefined, it will use default.png.

Answer (score 2):

[Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (??) was helpful for me:

```
[src]="item.pictureUrl ?? 'assets/img/logo.png'"
```