# concat src img with condition in angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

i try to show image of users in template angular from api call .So if the image is emty i will show any other img but if image is null i should make condition in src img :

```
 <img [src]="element.img!= null ? 'http://api.pointeuse.clediss.online/{{element.img}}' :
          'https://img2.freepng.fr/20180523/tha/kisspng-businessperson-computer-icons-avatar-clip-art-lattice-5b0508dc6a3a10.0013931115270566044351.jpg'"
          class="img-thumbnail border-0" />
```

the problem is i need to concate `{{element.img}}` with my base url

Comment: maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919087/conditional-image-src-binding-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Use a get method.

.html:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl"/>
```

.ts:

```
get imageUrl(): string {
   return this.element.img != null ? `some_url/${this.element.img}` : `other_url`;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, if you found this answer helpful please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.component.ts` file, make this a computed property is one approach

```
get elementImage(): string {
  if (this.element.image !== null) {
    return `http://api.pointeuse.clediss.online/${this.element.image}`
  } else {
    return 'https://img2.freepng.fr/20180523/tha/kisspng-businessperson-computer-icons-avatar-clip-art-lattice-5b0508dc6a3a10.0013931115270566044351.jpg'
}
```

in your template, it would be

```
<img [src]="elementImage" class="img-thumbnail border-0" />
```